# Using Mp4Parser, If I append more videos, the audiostream gest out of sync

Tags: android, video, append, concatenation, mp4parser

As i said, with more videos I do, the audio gets more and more out of sync. How can i fix this? I have the following code to append the videos;

```
public class ConcatenateVideos extends ExecutorAsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

private ArrayList<String> video_urls = null;

private final String TAG = ConcatenateVideos.class.getSimpleName();

public void setUris(ArrayList<String> videos) {
    LogService.log(TAG, "set uris");
    if (videos != null) {
        video_urls = videos;
        this.execute();
    }
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    boolean success = false;

    FileInputStream[] videos = new FileInputStream[video_urls.size()];

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < video_urls.size(); i++) {
            videos[i] = new FileInputStream(video_urls.get(i));
        }

        success = concatenateVideos(videos);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        success = false;
        LogService.err(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return success;
}

private boolean concatenateVideos(InputStream[] video_streams) {
    boolean success = false;
    Movie[] inMovies = new Movie[video_streams.length];

    FileChannel fc = null;
    Movie result = new Movie();
    IsoFile out = null;

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < inMovies.length; i++) {
            if (video_streams[i] != null) {
                inMovies[i] = MovieCreator.build(Channels.newChannel(video_streams[i]));
            }
        }
        List<Track> videoTracks = new LinkedList<Track>();
        List<Track> audioTracks = new LinkedList<Track>();

        for (Movie m : inMovies) {
            for (Track t : m.getTracks()) {
                if (t.getHandler().equals("soun")) {
                    audioTracks.add(t);
                }
                if (t.getHandler().equals("vide")) {
                    videoTracks.add(t);
                }
            }
        }

        if (audioTracks.size() > 0) {

            result.addTrack(new AppendTrack(audioTracks.toArray(new Track[audioTracks.size()])));

        }
        if (videoTracks.size() > 0) {

            result.addTrack(new AppendTrack(videoTracks.toArray(new Track[videoTracks.size()])));

        }
        out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(result);
        fc = new RandomAccessFile(video_urls.get(0), "rw").getChannel();
        for (int i = 1; i < video_urls.size(); i++) {
            File f = new File(video_urls.get(i));
            LogService.log(TAG, "delete file : "  + f.delete());
        }
        success = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogService.err(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        success = false;
    } finally {
        try {
            LogService.log(TAG, "==========finally");
            if (fc != null) {
                fc.position(0);
                out.getBox(fc);
                fc.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogService.err(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    return success;
}

 }
```

And this is the Service I use to call this ConcatenateVideos function:

```
 private final String TAG = ConcatenateVideosService.class.getSimpleName();
final Messenger myMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());

class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
    private Messenger client = null;

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        // init messenger
        if (client == null) {
            client = msg.replyTo;
        }

        // get the message
        Bundle data = msg.getData();
        byte dataString = data.getByte("message");

        switch (dataString) {
        case Constants.INIT_CMD_SERVICE:
            LogService.log(TAG, "INIT_CMD_SERVICE:");

            break;

        case Constants.CONCATE_CMD_SERVICE:
            LogService.log(TAG, "CONCATE_CMD_SERVICE:");

            ArrayList<String> videos = data.getStringArrayList(Constants.SERVICE_VIDEO_URLS);

            ConcatenateVideos concatenateVideos = new ConcatenateVideos() {
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                    LogService.log(TAG, "onPostExecute() ,  result : " + result);
                    super.onPostExecute(result);

                    // setup the answer
                    Message answer = Message.obtain();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                    bundle.putBoolean("result", result);
                    answer.setData(bundle);

                    // send the answer
                    try {
                        client.send(answer);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        LogService.err(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                    }
                }
            };
            concatenateVideos.setUris(videos);
            break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    stopSelf();
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return myMessenger.getBinder();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

My videos are recorded at he following quality: `VideoBitrate - 800000`, `audioBR - 64000`, `audioSamplingRate - 44100`, `MPEG_4. H264 Container`, `.AAC at 30fps`.
Now I made a test, and if I make 4 videos, the video `Timescale is 90000`, audio `Timescale is 44100` for every video.
But after appending the videos, the audio `TimeScale` of the videos is still `44100`, but the video `Timescale` is: `900`. Why does the `VideoTimeScale` change and not the audio one?

Comment: Any solution to this problem?

Comment: not yet. If I will manage something, I will let you know

Comment: I am getting the same issue, did you find any solution to it ?

Comment: Didn't find an answer, sorry

Answer (score 2):

In many case the recordings (audio / video) have different lengths. Let's say audio recordings are always 10.0 s and video are always 10.1 s. If you just play one movie like that audio may end before the video. It's kind of automatically silenced.

If you add two of these videos the first audio starts at 0 s and the second 10.0 - unfortunately the second video starts are 10.1 and voilà you got a sync problem.

You will need to compensate the different run lengths by appending silence or even by dropping some frames!

Comment: I tried appending silence but seems like the problem is not the video starting at 10.1 but actually the audio starting at 10.1, the lips will stop moving and the voice will still be playing, when I appended teh silence seemed to make it worse tbh, how do you drop frames to compensate however, would like to give this method a shot

Comment: So I think I may have solved the issue, the audio is longer than the video, so to fix this there needs to be a little extra video appended to the end of each video, roughly around 0.25 seconds or so, I will be attempting to do this this week, Ill let you know what happens, however if you can tell me how to drop frames to align the video that way I will attempt this as well

Comment: Attempted this but appears I cant get it to work, the only option is to drop frames but I cant find information how to do this so far

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: @SebastianAnnies do you plan to add a proper support for merging videos to mp4parser? I mean that if the library is supposed to support merging of videos it should handle overflow video/audio tracks and don't include then in the result file. It rather should not be expected that the client code of the library should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I faced same problem without a clear solution and taking code from here and there I made a couple of functions to solve this problem.

```
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun appendVideos(videoPathList: List<String>, targetFilePath: String) {

    val movies = videoPathList.flatMap { file -> listOf(MovieCreator.build(file)) }

    val finalMovie = Movie()

    val videoTracksTotal = mutableListOf<Track>()
    val audioTracksTotal = mutableListOf<Track>()

    var audioDuration = 0.0
    var videoDuration = 0.0

    movies.forEach { movie ->

        val videoTracks = mutableListOf<Track>()
        val audioTracks = mutableListOf<Track>()

        movie.tracks.forEach { track ->

            val trackDuration = track.sampleDurations.toList()
                .map { t -> t.toDouble() / track.trackMetaData.timescale }.sum()

            if (track.handler == "vide") {
                videoDuration += trackDuration
                videoTracks.add(track)
            } else if (track.handler == "soun") {
                audioDuration += trackDuration
                audioTracks.add(track)
            }
        }

        // Adjusting Durations
        adjustDurations(videoTracks, audioTracks, videoDuration, audioDuration).let {
            audioDuration = it.audioDuration
            videoDuration = it.videoDuration
        }

        videoTracksTotal.addAll(videoTracks)
        audioTracksTotal.addAll(audioTracks)
    }

    if (videoTracksTotal.isNotEmpty() && audioTracksTotal.isNotEmpty()) {
        finalMovie.addTrack(AppendTrack(*videoTracksTotal.toTypedArray()))
        finalMovie.addTrack(AppendTrack(*audioTracksTotal.toTypedArray()))
    }

    val container = DefaultMp4Builder().build(finalMovie)

    val fos = FileOutputStream(targetFilePath)
    val bb = Channels.newChannel(fos)
    container.writeContainer(bb)
    fos.close()
}

class Durations(val audioDuration: Double, val videoDuration: Double)

private fun adjustDurations(
    videoTracks: MutableList<Track>,
    audioTracks: MutableList<Track>,
    videoDuration: Double,
    audioDuration: Double
): Durations {

    var diff = audioDuration - videoDuration
    val tracks: MutableList<Track>
    var durationOperator: Double
    val isAudioProblem: Boolean

    when {
        // audio and video match, no operations to perform
        diff == 0.0 -> {
            return Durations(audioDuration, videoDuration)
        }
        // audio tracks are longer than video
        diff > 0 -> {
            tracks = audioTracks
            durationOperator = audioDuration
            isAudioProblem = true
        }
        // video tracks are longer than audio
        else -> {
            tracks = videoTracks
            durationOperator = videoDuration
            diff *= -1.0
            isAudioProblem = false
        }
    }

    // Getting the last track in order to operate with it
    var track: Track = tracks.last()
    var counter: Long = 0

    // Reversing SampleDuration list
    track.sampleDurations.toList().asReversed().forEach { sampleDuration ->

        // Calculating how much this track need to be re-adjusted
        if (sampleDuration.toDouble() / track.trackMetaData.timescale > diff) {
            return@forEach
        }
        diff -= sampleDuration.toDouble() / track.trackMetaData.timescale
        durationOperator -= sampleDuration.toDouble() / track.trackMetaData.timescale
        counter++
    }

    if (counter != 0L) {
        // Cropping track
        track = CroppedTrack(track, 0, track.samples.size - counter)

        //update the original reference
        tracks.removeAt(tracks.lastIndex)
        tracks.add(track)
    }

    // Returning durations
    return if (isAudioProblem) {
        Durations(durationOperator, videoDuration)
    } else {
        Durations(audioDuration, durationOperator)
    }
}
```